# location of instructions for config of apache 2.4 directory structure

Tags: 16.04, permissions, apache2, php7

Can anyone, please, either direct me to instructions for the setup of a directory structure for apache 2.4 on ubuntu 16.04 as follows :

```
www
 html (contains .php+ .html files)
 css  (contains .css files)
 images (contains jpegs)
 php  (contains php libraries)
```

`ls -l /home/user/www/`

```
drwxrwxr-x 8 user www-data   4096 Aug 31 23:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user       4096 Aug 31 19:33 ..
drwxrws--- 2 user www-data   4096 Aug 31 19:03 css
drwxrwsr-x 7 user www-data   4096 Aug 31 23:23 html
drwxrws--- 3 user www-data   4096 Aug 28 16:31 images
drwxrws--- 3 user www-data   4096 Aug 29 09:49 php
```

PHP works in html directory but does not access css, images or php directory.  I am receiving no error messages.

or help with corrections.

Here is the content of my 000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
#ServerName www.example.com 
ServerAdmin russ.c.davis@gmail.com 
DocumentRoot /home/rcdavis/www/html 
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
<Directory /home/rcdavis/www/html> 
    Options indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride ALL Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

Comment: Your `ls` query simply explains why you are not able access images, php and css. You have not given read access to **other** use groups as it says; `---` on them.  Can you do a `chmod 755 /home/use/www/` on a terminal an let us know?

Comment: Also your **root** should be `/home/user/www/` not the **html** If I recall the set-up correct. This is based on your configuration as you have redirected your root to the user's home. Or you will need to move the rest of the directories into the `html` folder if `/home/rcdavis/www/html` to stay as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to /etc/apache2/sites-available and go into 000-default.conf what do you see?

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName www.mydomain.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

I would recomend moving all of your folders into a domain specific folder as symLinks seem like a bad idea to me for example

```
sudo mkdir /home/rcdavis/www/MYSITE
cd /home/rcdavis/www
sudo mv !(MYSITE|MYSITE) MYSITE
sudo mv MYSITE /var/www/MYSITE
```

And then update your 000-default.conf to look something like: (Edit: Provided after)

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    #ServerName www.example.com 
    ServerAdmin russ.c.davis@gmail.com 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MYSITE
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44817/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-turnip-location-of-instructions-for-config-of-apache).